# PHP exec() runs the code but doesn't work completely

Tags: php, bash, exec

In some part of my code I compare 2 files and output the difference to another file by using `exec()` function.

In `exec` function I use `comm -13 <(sort file_a) <(sort file_b) > output`

When I run my php code, it creates output file but the file itself is empty. When I directly copy&paste the command into terminal, it also populates the file with differences but it doesn't populate my output file on php.

Part of the code;

```
exec('bash -c \'comm -13 <(sort "' . $path_d_raw.$least_recent_raw_file . '") <(sort "' . $path_d_raw.$most_recent_raw_file . '") > test.txt 2>&1\'', $output, $return);
```

`$path_d_raw.$least_recent_raw_file and $path_d_raw.$most_recent_raw_file` has correct path,/file tested it hundred times.

I also tried with `shell_exec` but couldn't get it done in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compare file sizes by using filesize() function, you can also echo the value.

```
    <?php

// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt: 1024 bytes

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
echo $filename . ': ' . filesize($filename) . ' bytes';

?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.filesize.php

Comment: This doesn't have to do anything about file size :) It's about comparing 2 files and print the differences

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be an escaping problem. You should use [proper functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to escape arguments and (in this case) commands. Try this out:

```
<?php
$command = sprintf(
    "comm -13 <(sort %s) <(sort %s) > test.txt 2>&1",
    escapeshellarg($path_d_raw . $least_recent_raw_file),
    escapeshellarg($path_d_raw . $most_recent_raw_file)
);
$escaped_command = escapeshellarg($command);
exec("bash -c $escaped_command", $output, $return);
```

We escape twice because you are passing the command itself to another shell for execution.

I would also suggest writing to a file located at an absolute path, in a separate directory. The fact that your web server can write to the directory where executable PHP scripts are stored should concern you.

Comment: Thanks @miken32, the code still executes without any issue but it still doesn't populate differences to new file. I checked permissions issue several time, but it only creates `test.txt` file but doesn't populate it.